# I'm trying to open ports for a VM instance that will be a CS:GO server, but they are not opening

Tags: port, firewall

I tried opening ports for a `CS:GO` server on google cloud, but nothing works. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Here is a screenshot of my firewall:
[image]

Here is a screenshot when I run `netstat -an`:
[image]

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, you've assigned the csgo network tag to your VM in GCE, right?

Comment: @GabeWeiss Yes, of course.

Comment: Looks like you're missing "-51840 UDP" for outbound connection.

Might also have to register it? I haven't run one myself, just doing a little research and found a couple folks talking about accessibility for it.